# CentOS exec(): Unable to fork issue

Tags: php, apache, centos, sphinx

In a php script, i am rotating sphinx indexes using exec command as below,

```
echo exec('/usr/bin/indexer --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf --all --rotate');
```

This exec called using a for loop, Most of the time, i got success message. But in some cases, i got warning message like below,

Severity: Warning

```
<p>Message:  exec(): Unable to fork [/usr/bin/indexer --config /etc/sphinx/sphinx.conf --all --rotate]</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/runscript.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 306</p>
```

Please suggest on this issue.

Regards,
Raja MM

Comment: And why you need a for loop to index sphinx ?

Comment: Yes. I need to execute the sphinx rotate command with specified interval (10 seconds).

Comment: 10 seconds? Thats really short. If ever one of those indexers happens to take over 10 seconds, the first will still be running, meaning the second fails. Suggest using RT indexes instead, if you REALLY need things to be updated that quickly.

Comment: btw, the reason that is bad, every 10 seconds, your searchd server will effectivly be restarted. Thats a LOT of overhead. And going to seriouslly affect perfomance, (unless your indexes are really trivial in size)